# nth_value window function giving unexpected error

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, window-functions

I am trying to solve 12th question from [this](https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Guest_House_Assessment_Hard) link using window function, the desired output is:

[image]

The schema for the database is:

[image]

to do so I first created a temporary table using the following code:

```
select 
distinct adddate(booking_date, nights) as vacate_day, 
floor(room_no/100) as floor, 
sum(1) over (partition by vacate_day, floor(room_no/100)) as count
from booking
where adddate(booking_date, nights) between '2016-11-14' and '2016-11-20'
order by vacate_day, room_no;
```

this gave me the following result table:

[image]

Now what I am trying is- let's say to get only the count of first floor, I used nth_value to get the 1st value of count after paritioning by vacate_day and ordering by floor. I used following code:

```
select vacate_day, nth_value(count, 1) over (partition by vacate_day order by floor) as 1st 
from
(select 
distinct adddate(booking_date, nights) as vacate_day, 
floor(room_no/100) as floor, 
sum(1) over (partition by vacate_day, floor(room_no/100)) as count
from booking
where adddate(booking_date, nights) between '2016-11-14' and '2016-11-20'
order by vacate_day, room_no) as temp;
```

This gives the following error

> Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

I don't understand why it require me to group by , as from what I know that window function uses partitioning to group rows. Now, lets say I group by vacate_day to fix this error but when trying to get 2nd floor count using the following code it gives `null` for all rows. My final code that I think should work is following:

```
select vacate_day, 
nth_value(count, 1) over (partition by vacate_day order by floor) as 1st, nth_value(count,2) over (partition by vacate_day order by floor) as 2nd,
nth_value(count, 3) over (partition by vacate_day order by floor) as 3rd
from
(select 
distinct adddate(booking_date, nights) as vacate_day, 
floor(room_no/100) as floor, 
sum(1) over (partition by vacate_day, floor(room_no/100)) as count
from booking
where adddate(booking_date, nights) between '2016-11-14' and '2016-11-20'
order by vacate_day, room_no) as temp
group by vacate_day;
```

Output that I get from this code is:

[image]

PS: I think I am missing some logical point here and not syntactical error, also I have an easy solution but my real problem is with this implementation which I think should work.

Comment: Your question is incomplete.  I'm not going to another site to see what the data looks like.

Comment: I have added necessary details @GordonLinoff